# как на Python 3 выполнить SNMP запрос? Какую библиотеку использовать, чтобы была менее громоздкая?

Tags: python, snmp

Как можно упростить или какую библиотеку использовать?
Я пытался делать SNMP запрос так:

```
import pysnmp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import Integer, IpAddress, OctetString

from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from ipaddress import *


def get_name(comm, ip, oid):
    
    return (getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                   CommunityData(commun),
                   UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
                   ContextData(),
                   ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid))))
#
def snmp_get_text(comm, ip, oid):    
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(get_name(commun, ip, oid))
    for name, val in varBinds:
        return ( val.prettyPrint())
        

sys_name = (snmp_get_text(commun, ip ,oid))
```

Получается слишком громоздко, учитывая, что с помощью утилиты SnmpWalk.exe или в Линуксе можно в одну строку выполнить такой запрос.

Comment: это не так громоздко как парсить текстовый вывод SnmpWalk

Comment: В таком случае как получить с помощью такого SNMP-запроса версию IOS , например? Тут можно получить только имя устройства

Comment: Oid подставляй и получай все нужно

Comment: Просто любой OID подставить и будет возвращать значение по нему? Может как-то сам код поправить для оптимизации?

Comment: да тут бред с циклами непонятный у вас

Comment: А если вот так сделать:

Comment: def get_snmp(get_comm, get_ip, get_oid):
    try:
        obj_type = [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(get_oid))]
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
                getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                    CommunityData(get_comm),
                    UdpTransportTarget((get_ip, 161)),
                    ContextData() ,
                    *obj_type
                    )
            )
        for name, val in varBinds:
            return (val.prettyPrint())

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

Comment: И в чём именно "бред с циклами" ?

Comment: ретурн на первой итерации - сделал бы next как во второй функции

Comment: спасибо. Попробую